# jquery flot, graph point not place correct

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jquery-plugins, flot

my graph get data from server, time server * 1000 for convert to time js. And here my graph

http://awesomescreenshot.com/03f1ft5k72

The poin not match the column day. I must + 25 000 000 to each value to show it match column day. Why this happen,I'm new with flot. Can you share me your experence.

```
var d_register = #{ @total.map{ |t| [t.date.to_time.to_i * 1000 , t.register] } };
// must add 25 000 000 to it for correct position point.
// var d_register = #{ @total.map{ |t| [t.date.to_time.to_i * 1000 + 25000000, t.register] } };
var curr = new Date(#{Date.current.to_time.to_i * 1000}); // get current date
define_flot();

function define_flot(){
        var first = new Date(curr.getTime() - curr.getDay() * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
        var last = new Date(first.getTime() + 7 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
        $(".week-time").text(
          (first.getMonth() + 1) + '/' +
          first.getDate() + '/' +
          first.getFullYear() + ' - ' +

          (last.getMonth() + 1) + '/' +
          last.getDate() + '/' +
          last.getFullYear()  );

        var first_day_in_week = first.getTime();
        var last_day_in_week = last.getTime();
        $.plot("#placeholder", [ d_register ], {
            yaxis: {
                    tickDecimals: 0
            },
            xaxis: {
                    mode: "time",
                    minTickSize: [1, "day"],
                    min: first_day_in_week,
                    max: last_day_in_week,
                    timeformat: "%a"
            }
        });
    }
```

data_register :

[[1370710800000, 1], [1370797200000, 7], [1370883600000, 1], [1371056400000, 0], [1371142800000, 0], [1371747600000, 0], [1371834000000, 0], [1371920400000, 0], [1372006800000, 0], [1372093200000, 0], [1372179600000, 0]]

data_register after + 25000000:

[[1370735800000, 1], [1370822200000, 7], [1370908600000, 1], [1371081400000, 0], [1371167800000, 0], [1371772600000, 0], [1371859000000, 0], [1371945400000, 0], [1372031800000, 0], [1372118200000, 0], [1372204600000, 0]]

Comment: Can you provide an example of one of your timestamp values, and the day it's supposed to correspond to?

Comment: sorry for delay, I just add some code and data. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your screenshot link appears to have broken, but as I recall the problem was that the values were supposed to be aligned to the beginning of a day, but were showing offset by a few hours.

The problem is that Flot expects UTC timestamps, while yours are offset.  1370710800000, for example, is actually June 8, 2013 at 17:00 GMT.  By adding 25M - 1370735800000 - that becomes 23:56:40, which is close enough that it appears to line up to the day boundary.  Really what you want to add is 7 (hours) * 3600 (seconds) * 1000 (milliseconds) = 25200000, which compensates for what I'm assuming is your local timezone offset of GMT-7, US Pacific Time.